# what does 'T' mean between Qt.ISODate output?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a rather simple question 
this is part of my code

```
now = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
# print('Local datetime: ', now.toString())
print('Local datetime: ', now.toString(Qt.ISODate))
```

output is:

```
Local datetime:  2018-03-21T13:38:33
```

my question is, what does 'T' mean between output?

Answer (score 2):

The `"T"` indicates the beginning of a timestamp in ISO 8601 standards.

**[MoreInfo](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)**

From Wiki:

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete
>   date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid time
>   expression. For example, "2007-04-05T14:30".